# xml search and update using python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

my sample xml object is:

```
    <Assessment version="10" dateCreated="4/19/2020 10:41:20 PM">
     <Section name="Space">
     <Glossary>
      <Item name="***">&lt;b&gt;Indicates high priority data that is required&lt;/b&gt;</Item>
    </Glossary>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100" title="[1a] q2 some data">
      <Value>20</Value>
    </InputNumber>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="10000" title="[2] some data">
      <Value>1</Value>
    </InputNumber>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="10000" title="[3] some text">
      <Value>2</Value>
     </InputNumber>
    </Section>
    <Section name="Power">
    <Glossary>
      <Item name="***">&lt;b&gt;Indicates high priority data that is required&lt;/b&gt;</Item>
    </Glossary>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100000" title="[8] some text">
      <Value>15</Value>
    </InputNumber>
    <PickList title="[11] some text">
      <Option selected="true">Yes</Option>
      <Option>No</Option>
      <Option>there is no UPS</Option>
    </PickList>
    </Section>
    <Section name="Cooling">
    <Glossary>
      <Item name="***">&lt;b&gt;Indicates high priority data that is required&lt;/b&gt;</Item>
    </Glossary>
    <InputNumber type="int" min="0" max="100000" title="[18] some text">
      <Value>30</Value>
    </InputNumber>
    </InputText>
    <InputText title="[21] some data">
      <Value>3</Value>
    </InputText>
  </Section>
   <Section name="Comments">
    <InputTextArea title="[22] General Comments" format="normal">
      <Value>test value for capacity assessment test by monika</Value>
    </InputTextArea>
  </Section>
</Assessment>
```

i get this from database

In my python script:

```
template= cursor.fetchall()
    for row in template:
        #xmlTemplate = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(row[6]))
        xmlTemplateStr = row[6]
        xmlTemplate = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xmlTemplateStr))
        root = ET.fromstring(xmlTemplateStr)
```

i need to find the node based on the number and update the value of that perticular node

for example:
if in need to update the following value to 4:

```
</InputText>
<InputText title="[21] some data">
<Value>3</Value>
</InputText>
```

i need to search the node with key as [21] and update the value of that node to 4

```
</InputText>
<InputText title="[21] some data">
<Value>4</Value>
</InputText>
```

How do i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with lxml, using xpath:

```
assess = """[your xml above - corrected]""" #note: the sample xml in the question was invalid because it had an extra tag

from lxml import etree
doc = etree.XML(assess.encode('utf-8'))
val = doc.xpath('//InputText[@title="[21] some data"]/Value')
val[0].text = '4'
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Relevant part of the output:

```
<InputText title="[21] some data">
         <Value>4</Value>
</InputText>
```